# Can I use iframe to protect my content from being edit?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like to do Facebook like button for choice A B and C and I want my client to choose only one. So I'm planing to put it into iframe with Javascript code(that force client to only can like 1 like button) and then embed to other website. Can this concept protect my code from being edit by client? or there are other way to achieve this?

Comment: That should be good enough to block cross domain access to the data you display inside the iframe. Also, make sure you dont serve out clients' sites/content from your domain. If you do, ensure they can't inject scripts in there.

Comment: Do you mean I can force my client to click only on one Facebook like button(like button from Facebook)? The only point I scared is that they will write some code to unlock my script and then be able to like more than one button. can they do that? I'm using goggle app engine to host this web app, so I need to separate into two server? or just two domain name?

Comment: Should be OK as long as 1) The page fragment containing the three choices and the three like buttons is served from your domain (say abc.com). and 2) The client's web page is never served from the domain abc.com

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Anything and everything you send to the client can be edited.
ALWAYS handle your final validation server-side.

The other website you're embedding it in can't access your code, however.

Comment: so if I place the like button on website A with script that force client to be able to click only one like button and then embed into iframe and place into website B, the client in website B can click only one like button but can't edit the js code inside the iframe. Am I understand correctly or I misunderstand?

Comment: The user __can__ edit your js / html. Site B __can't__ access / edit it.

Comment: you mean people on site B can't access and edit my iframe??? do you mean they can click on the like button but can't edit the js or they can't do anything and can't click like button?

Comment: Okay, there's a difference between a "User" and a "Site"
A user is a person browsing the web. They can ALWAYS edit JS they see. With a "Site", I mean html / js loaded from external sources. JS from site B can not access anything that's in site A.

Comment: so if I place the like button on website A with script that force client to be able to click only one like button and then embed into iframe and place into website B, the client in website B can click only one like button but can't edit the js code inside the iframe. Am I understand correctly or I misunderstand?

Comment: Like I said, __The client can ALWAYS edit your code__